# Primefaces InputSwitch Component Duplicating After Ajax Requests

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

In a web application there is a form to the user register some values, which one of them is the **prefixo**. When a **prefixo** value is selected, a  [selectCheckboxMenu](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml) is (ajax) populated with **Executivos** values. This is working fine and, if the user click on Save button, it is correctly persisted in the database.

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{adeBundle.CreateDemandasLabel_prefixo}" for="prefixo" />
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="prefixo" value="#{demandasController.selected.prefixo}"  converter="prefixosConverter" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" required="true" requiredMessage="#{adeBundle.CreateDemandasRequiredMessage_prefixo}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{adeBundle.SelectOneMessage}" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{prefixosController.items}"
                       var="prefixoItem"
                       itemValue="#{prefixoItem}"
                       itemLabel="#{prefixoItem.prefixo} - #{prefixoItem.nomePrefixo}"
                       />
        <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="uorPosCollection" listener="#{demandasController.changePrefixo}"/>                            
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:tooltip for="prefixo" value="#{demandasController.getComponentMessages('prefixo', adeBundle.CreateDemandasHelpText_prefixo)}"/>
</h:panelGroup>

<p:outputLabel value="#{adeBundle.CreateDemandasLabel_uorPosCollection}" for="uorPosCollection" />
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="uorPosCollection" value="#{demandasController.selected.uorPosCollection}" label="Executivo(s)" multiple="true" 
                      converter="uorPosConverter" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" panelStyle="width:420px" dynamic="true" title="Selecione um ou mais..." >
    <f:selectItems value="#{demandasController.availableExecutivos}"
                   var="uorPosCollectionItem"
                   itemValue="#{uorPosCollectionItem}"
                   itemLabel="#{uorPosCollectionItem.matricula} - #{uorPosCollectionItem.nome} (#{uorPosCollectionItem.prefixo.prefixo})"
                   >
         <p:inputSwitch disabled="#{demandasController.selected.uorPosCollection.size()==0}" value="#{demandasController.valueOnExecutivo}" onLabel="Sim" offLabel="Não" showLabels="true" style="float: right"><p:ajax listener="#{demandasController.addEmailAdviseMessage}" update=":growl" /></p:inputSwitch>
         <p:outputLabel value="Enviar e-Mail:&nbsp;" style="float: right; padding-top: 0.5em" />
    </f:selectItems>
    <p:tooltip for="uorPosCollection" value="#{demandasController.getComponentMessages('uorPosCollection', adeBundle.CreateDemandasHelpText_uorPosCollection)}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

The problem is: everytime when the user selects a Prefixo, the [inputSwitch](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputSwitch.xhtml) is duplicated:

[image]

Does anyone knows why this is happening and how can I fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put your `<p:inputSwitch>` outside the `<f:selectItems>`.
Then put an `<p:ajax>` to update the inputSwitch value.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me.